# Do operator on a 2 node system

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality, intervention-analysis

If my causal structure consists of $y$ influencing $x$ (so the DAG would simply be $y\to x$), my understanding is that $p(x|do(y=1))=p(x|y=1)$. But what is wrong with the following argument?
$$p(x|do(y=1))=p(x|y=1)=\frac{p(x,y=1)}{p(y=1)}=p(x)?$$ Because $p(y=1)=1$ due to the intervention.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong?

Comment: Because this makes it look like intervening on the "cause" of $x$ actually doesn't affect $x$.

Comment: So the only thing I can think of that might be wrong is if you're claiming $p(y=1)=1$ due to the intervention. We're talking probabilities here, and that's usually an *a priori* category, not *a posteriori*. Are you computing $p(y=1)$ before the intervention or after? Would the interpretation of the expression $p(y=1)$ change accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Adrian Keister points at the critical distinction. At the first equals sign you have correctly translated the do-expression into a purely statistical expression. From the second expression onward there is no do-operator so the reasoning that P(Y=1) would be equal to 1 due to the intervention does not apply here anymore.